# VLC does not start after first video played

Tags: vlc

When playing videos using VLC, which I start from Nautilus, the first video always plays well. Subsequent videos (often the second video) do not play anymore, if I close the first video and open the second video (or even the first again), nothing happens.

The icon in the top menu bar does not close VLC when I choose close in the dropdown menu. If I reopen VLC or try to play the old video again, VLC does not react in any way.

For every click on a video from Nautilus, `/var/log/syslog` contains the following lines:

```
Jan 22 11:06:15 reichelt-desktop gnome-shell[2178]: message repeated 5 times: [ Window manager warning: Invalid WM_TRANSIENT_FOR window 0x2200008 specified for 0x220020a.]
Jan 22 11:06:28 reichelt-desktop gnome-shell[2178]: g_signal_handler_disconnect: assertion 'handler_id > 0' failed
Jan 22 11:06:28 reichelt-desktop gnome-shell[2178]: JS ERROR: TypeError: this._playerProxy is null#012_onPlayerProxyReady@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/mpris.js:184:9#012_makeProxyWrapper/</<@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/core/overrides/Gio.js:262:21
```

Running `ps -aux | grep vlc` and `kill -9` the VLC instance makes it possible to play another video, but it is very cumbersome to do this for every video.

I use a standard Ubuntu 20.04.

Is there any workaround / fix for this (besides switching the video player)?

The version of VLC is

```
VLC media player 3.0.9.2 Vetinari (revision 3.0.9.2-0-gd4c1aefe4d)
VLC-Version 3.0.9.2 Vetinari (3.0.9.2-0-gd4c1aefe4d)
Kompiliert von buildd auf lgw01-amd64-060.buildd (Apr  9 2020 19:29:44)
Kompiler: gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2)
Dieses Programm kommt OHNE GEWÄHRLEISTUNG.
Sie dürfen das Programm unter den Bedingungen der GNU General Public License weitergegeben;
Für Details bitte die Datei COPYING ansehen.
Geschrieben von der VideoLAN-Gruppe; zu sehen in der AUTHORS-Datei.
```

Comment: Is this for the snap version of VLC?

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I should have posted the version. Its for the regular `apt` version - due to technical issues, I removed `snap` completely.

Comment: I had a similar problem with both the snap version and apt. In the end, I decided on the default `Videos` app also known as `Totem` which I manged to use without incident after installing the multimedia codecs using [this](https://linuxhint.com/install_multimedia_codecs_ubuntu/) guide.

Comment: If you are using an AMD graphic card, what works for me was to change the Hardware-accelerated decoding codec from Automatic to VA-API video decoder

Answer (score 0):

I have vlc:

```
➜  ~ vlc --version
VLC media player 3.0.9.2 Vetinari (revision 3.0.9.2-0-gd4c1aefe4d)
VLC version 3.0.9.2 Vetinari (3.0.9.2-0-gd4c1aefe4d)
Compiled by buildd on lgw01-amd64-060.buildd (Apr  9 2020 19:29:44)
Compiler: gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2)
This program comes with NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
You may redistribute it under the terms of the GNU General Public License;
see the file named COPYING for details.
Written by the VideoLAN team; see the AUTHORS file.
```

and ubuntu:

```
➜  ~ uname -a
Linux mateusz-ThinkPad-T480s 5.13.0-28-generic #31~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 19 14:08:10 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

and I have created soft link to python3:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python
```

and vlc has started to work.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu and thank you for contributing.  Please take the [tour].